# asp net. How to remove data from a database

Tags: c#, asp.net, database

First I want to say I'm just starting to learn and I'm french, so please be very simple in your explanation. Just imagine you're talking to a 3 years old and I should be ok. Please don't overload me with dozens of lines of code without any explanation.

OK here's what I want to do: I have a very simple database table of article author. The table has 5 columns:

```
First Name, Second name, Dob, Phone Nb, Place of Birth, UserId
```

The `userId` is automatically created. I have created a form where a user would write the first name and second name (in 2 separated textboxes and I want to use that to fetch the userId in the table and use it to delete the entire line)

Here's the code for my form

```
    model projet_clement.Models.HomeModel

<form method="post" action="~/home/SupressionAuteur">
    <h3>deleting author page</h3>
    <p>first name of the author to delete</p>
    <input type="text" name="Nom" />
    <p>second name of the author to delete</p>
    <input type="text" name="Prenom" /><br />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Delete" />
</form>



<h3>For reminder, here's a table of the author already created</h3>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Nom</td>
        <td>Prenom</td>
        <td>Date de naissance</td>
        <td>N° de téléphone</td>
        <td>Département de naissance</td>
        <td>UserId</td>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var i in Model.UserList)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@i.Nom</td>
            <td>@i.Prenom</td>
            <td>@i.Naissance</td>
            <td>@i.Numero</td>
            <td>@i.Departement</td>
            <td>@i.userId</td>
        </tr>
    }

</table>
```

OK now what I would like to know is how can I get the userId thanks to the first name and second name, and how can I delete a whole row just using this id.

Here's my c# code

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult SupressionAuteur()
{
     var allUsers = db.Users.Where(x => x.Nom != null);

     var model = new HomeModel(allUsers);
     return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SupressionAuteur(Users formUser)
{
    //for those who skipped french class, nom = first name and prenom = second name;)
    var userId = db.Users.Where(x => x.Nom == formUser.Nom && x.prenom == formuser.prenom);
    db.Users.Remove([What should i write here?]);
    return RedirectToAction("SupressionAuteur", "Home");
}
```

Of course it doesn't work!

When I run my code the userId var never get the good value. So I guess the way I try to get it is wrong

And how am I supposed to use the `db.users.remove()` method? Is it the one I should use by the way? I was told so.

Thanks in advance, I'm really stuck :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Steps

1. Get the user - *ideally you want to use the userid (or primary key) to retrieve the user*
2. Remove the user from the db
3. Save the changes in the context

Code:

```
var user = db.Users.Single(x => x.Nom == formUser.Nom && x.prenom == formuser.prenom);
db.Users.Remove(user);
db.SaveChanges();
```